# Powershell Script for Verifying software is installed

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have been working with a powershell script to verify that a specific version of software is installed and at least a specific version. This is what I have and it works.

```
`$software = "Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools";
 $version = "7.8.1.244"
 $installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |       Where { $_.DisplayVersion -eq $version }) -ne $null

 If(-Not $installed) {
Write-Host "'$software' NOT is installed.";
 } else {
Write-Host "'$software' is installed."
 }
 `
```

I am trying to set it to use something like -ge to verify that the version is greater than or equal to the above version. When I switch it to -ge instead of -eq it basically says everything is installed.

Is there a way around this?

I have tried

```
 `$software = "Bitdefender Endpoint Security Tools";
  $version = "7.8.1.244"
  $installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |   Where { $_.DisplayVersion -ge $version }) -ne $null

  If(-Not $installed) {
Write-Host "'$software' NOT is installed.";
  } else {
Write-Host "'$software' is installed."
  }
  `
```

Answer (score 0):

You could break down the version yourself by splitting the current version into it's counterparts:

- Major release;
- Minor release;
- Bugfix release;
- Build number.

Then for each release you can compare what is actually installed vs what your known latest version is:

- Installed version is equal to last known (and company supported) version;
- Installed version is lower than last known (and company supported) version;
- Installed version is higher than last known (and company supported) version.